# Filter Firestore updating document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My app keeps crashing when I try to update a document. What am I doing wrong?

```
 Future<bool> updateEvent(data, id) async {
    try {
      final _ref = _db.collection('content').doc(id);
      print(_ref);
      await _ref.update(data);

      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

`print(_ref)` returns

```
flutter: DocumentReference(content/KwaKlb1GpUbqSQd8K9rd)
```

`data` is set like this

```
final data = {
      "active": true,
      "title": _titleTextController.text != null
          ? _titleTextController.text
          : null,
  ...
};
```

Comment: if you can print the error and update that error in question it will be very helpful

Comment: I'm not getting any error. That's what is weird. It just says lost connection to device.

Comment: go into the logcat..
there you can find the error.
even after the app crash

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that. But it will be helpful. I will check online how to view the logcat. Thanks! I am using an iPhone emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final data = {
  "active": true,
  if(_titleTextController.text != null)
  "title": _titleTextController.text
      
 };
```

Should only add the field if it's not null or you can use ?? to assign a default value

Comment: Ok. Makes sense ... but the title is always set. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To answer properly, it would be good to see your error message. I don't currently use Firestore with the Flutter, but if it works like Firestore on other platforms, it will not allow setting a Null -value to a field. This will happen in your example when the text is empty.